# Push View Controller Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, view

I am trying to push to a new view controller when I click the quiz button I implemented. I set it up as below:

```
    quizButton = UIButton()
    quizButton.setTitle(" Quiz ", for: .normal)
    quizButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    quizButton.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    quizButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    quizButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(takeQuiz), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(quizButton)
```

and I defined the function takeQuiz as below, where there is a separate view controller called QuizViewController:

```
@objc func takeQuiz() {
   let newViewController = QuizViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

I'm not sure if it was necessary for me to use delegates here, since I am not trying to relay any information from one view controller to the other. Let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "use delegates"? Your code will work fine, but I don't think it has any delegates.

Comment: Delegate is something that is used for passing data or some action to notify an object for which we want to delegate.. So here it doesn't think you are not passing anything or wanted to observe any action.

Comment: @SachinVsSachin I am a little confused by your wording.. should I be delegating here then? All I wanted to do was push to a new view.

Comment: @jukebox41188, use of delegation is not required here, as above your code does not expect to data return back..

Comment: @SachinVsSachin that's what I figured. I am just a little stuck with what I am doing wrong here. I did something similar in another project and this was basically the same thing I had written.